# MongoDb won't start

Tags: mongodb

I went to restart my mongo db because I realized that I did not have `auth=true` set in my `mongo.conf` file.

I've never had problems restarting before.

I restarted by `sudo /etc/init.d/mongo` restart.

It failed to restarted.

When I look in the `mongo.log` file I see some errors.  The folder that it is complaining about is owned by root and not `mongod`.   I actually see about 5 folders that are owned by root in the data folder.

Is this normal?  Can I just change the permissions on this folder to mongod?

```
2015 - 07 - 18 T14: 18: 58.357 + 0000[initandlisten] recover: no journal files present, no recovery needed
2015 - 07 - 18 T14: 18: 58.689 + 0000[initandlisten] couldn 't open /data/product.28 errno:13 Permission denied

2015 - 07 - 18 T14: 18: 58.689 + 0000[initandlisten] Assertion: 16966: 
_extentManager.init failed: InternalError DataFile::openExisting - mmf.open failed
2015 - 07 - 18 T14: 18: 58.700 + 0000[initandlisten] 0x11e9b11 0x118b849 0x11703f6 0x117094c 0x8c2e65 0x8c51ab 0x8d3b1a 0x8f8ee5 0x8f9117 
0x76ad48 0x76c89f 0x76d14b 0x76d6e5 0x76d909 0x7f6e276887d5 0x764589Thanks for any insight or help in advance.
```

Karen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change the permissions for the data folder safely

```
sudo chown -R mongod:mongod /var/lib/mongodb
```

...or whatever DB path you have set. I also had to do it recently, because my MongoDB server crashed, and I had to repair. But the repaired files were created with wrong permissions

Comment: Thanks I fearlessly changed the permissions and it worked :)

Comment: Please mark as resolved then (the tick below the question points)